# The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'AllListsAux', database 'spContent', schema 'dbo'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, uls, sql-server-2012

> Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: NT
>   AUTHORITY\IUSR SID: S-1-5-17 ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in
>   database 'spContent' on SQL Server instance '###'

```
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'AllListsAux', database 'spContent', schema 'dbo'.
```

Above provided error message has been triggered when user performs File operation according to SharePoint ULS log:

> SPShareByLinkHandler.IsShareableByLink : ShareByLink disabled at
>   SPSite or tenant level    a2ebab9c-6704-709b-7964-af1a3b3839ad
>       08/06/2014 14:20:46.10    w3wp.exe (0x25DC)                           0x085C  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization 
>     ajp2l   Medium 
>     SPShareByLinkHandler.CanManageSharingLinkForNewDocument : container
>   is not shareable  a2ebab9c-6704-709b-7964-af1a3b3839ad
>       08/06/2014 14:20:46.11    w3wp.exe (0x25DC)                           0x2320  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     880i    High        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The
>   UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'AllListsAux',

I have no clue what is `SPShareByLinkHandler`?

What is `SPShareByLinkHandler`?

Thank You

Comment: What is the exact "file operation" you are trying to accomplish?  For example, is it a file upload to a SharePoint document library?

Answer (score -1):

As per [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/37f2e405-f65c-46b5-a01d-c9ad305fd083/the-update-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-alllistsaux-database-wsscontent-schema?forum=sharepointgeneral), this issue does not prevent the operation from completing successfully; and

> This issue has been fixed and is scheduled to be released in the SharePoint 2013 November 2015 CU. ﻿﻿

Comment: If this issue was to be resolved by a CU, it still exists in SP 2016 with June 2017 CU patch.